# Google Maps v3 becomes not-responding after zooming and third-finger touch on android

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I get an error of map not-responding in the next situation:

1. start to pinch-to-zoom map on mobile Chrome;
2. while holding pinch-to-zoom fingers, touch outside map area with the third finger;
3. holding the third finger, release first two fingers;
4. map stops reacting to any further interactions: no tiles loading, no touch
   events, nothing

Don't say that I am crazy :) But this really can happen when you accidentally touch screen with thumb finger while zooming. Especially on large screens.
I create fiddle and recorded video with issue reproducing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzuPjCUO3Eg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 300px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 48.2943203, lng: 0.6599207},
          zoom: 6,
          draggable: true,
          scrollwheel: true,
          zoomControl: false,          
          disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
        });          
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBRnbx52fgp8ko-LnpOQ9vPcoBhflJDgpI&language=en&callback=initMap&signed_in=false" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3vcjed3v/3/

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Tested on android 5-7 in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, xiaomi and samsung devices.

Comment: I reproduced this issue on my side and it looks like a valid bug. Do not hesitate to report it in Google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207).

Comment: I already filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70206421
But they won't fix it because new rederer doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Great, at least you have a workaround.